# Upgraded CiviCRM 4.4.6 to 4.5.4; Case is adding but its not showing?

Tags: civicase

Upgraded civicrm 4.4.6 to 4.5.4. Case is adding but its not showing?
I am using drupal-7.22.

[image: case not visible]

Comment: Intrigued - what's Orbit? Is it a custom edition of CiviCRM?

Comment: Also: You should DEFINITELY upgrade your Drupal installation, particularly if it's accessible on the internet. 7.22 has vulnerabilities which you need to address (and you'll need to review your existing site users/site codebase). Search "Drupageddon" for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Check your permissions, they may have changed and you'll need to give the relevant role the permissions. You should also clarify which CMS your using to make it easier to support you!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your logic is for upgrading to 4.5.4 but there have been changes with the way Case works and in some cases that requires the renaming of Case Type 'names' and the XML files but i would have expected you would have had some warnings post upgrade